# How can I deploy app only for iPhone 3Gs,4,4S and skip iPhone5 support?

Tags: iphone, build, app-store

I want upload app to app store for review but it seems like I need also iPhone 5 screenshots but I don't have app prepared for iPhone 5. Please, how can I deploy app only for iphone 3gs,4,4s?

I find something in Targets/Build Settings/**Architectures** Standard armv7 and **Base SDK** is Latest iOS 6.0. Is that what I have to change?

Comment: Thanks guys for replies. I've problem, because in my country iPhone 5 is still no available. So what are the next steps now? Will the app for iphone4 running on iphone 5? How it looks when you launch app for iPhone4 on iPhone5? It's similar like when you run iphone app on ipad? Or?

Comment: Thank you guys, I just finished app redesign for iPhone5 but without hardware testing. On simulator was everything ok and on iPhone4 and 4s with iOS6.0 runs everything smoothly. Hope now I'll be able to submit to app store...

Answer (score 1):

Just for absolute clarity, Apple released an announcement on March 21st 2013 stating that starting May 1st 2013 new apps and app updates **MUST** be built for iOS devices with Retina display and iPhone apps must also support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5.

You can view the announcement [here](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=3212013b#top).

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to just properly prepare your app for the iPhone 5's display. And no. Changing the base SDK will not help here.

Comment: One should not develop or submit apps for devices they don't have available for testing.  Just develop for the iPhone 4, and let Apple be responsible for the 5 do it's letterbox thing correctly.

Comment: @hotpaw2 yes, but there was the problem, I don't know how to do that. I don't know how to skip releasing app for iPhone5.

Comment: @alexhajdu : Use Xcode 4.4.x instead of 4.5.  It can be downloaded from the iOS Developer portal.

Comment: yes, maybe it will be my next option. now is app waiting for review so will wait for resolution...maybe i will have luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't, only apps submitted before iPhone5-release can run in "iPhone 4 mode" on the new iPhone. All updates to apps and newly submitted apps must support the new 4 inch screen.

You cannot exclude the iPhone5 in the target settings and if there were a way to do that, there is no way Apple would approve it. You can remove support for old devices, but never for new ones.

After all, Apple wants as many apps as possible to adapt the new format as soon as possible, and this is what you have to do... don't worry - if you are fairly used to developing to iOS you can do it in just a few hours...

Answer (score 0):

Apple has stated that theY will still (currently) be accepting apps without specific iOS 6 and iPhone 5 support when developed with an Xcode version prior to 4.5, and thus with an SDK 5.1 or earlier.  568h support is specifically not allowed in apps built that way.

Apps built that way will run in letterbox on a 5, or the similar 1X/2X compatibility boxes that the iPad uses for legacy iPhone only apps.

Answer (score 0):

I submitted an app following the release of the iPhone 5 with the latest version of XCode that runs letterboxed on the iPhone 5. Just remove armv7s from your supported architectures.

Comment: how can i remove it? what i should type there? I've there Standard (armv7, armv7s) - $ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT

Comment: I just have ARMV7 and ARMV6 in mine